# MySQL: Subquery unknown column

Tags: mysql

I'm running into an issue with my query. I have a database with orders, order transactions, order products and order shipping cost. Now I want all orders where the customer did not totally pay the order.

I created a database fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4MaVseQnmCkj84UGWYxDov/1).

With this query I can get the order total of a specific order, in this case order 1:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS orderTotal
FROM (
    SELECT order_id, SUM(price * amount) AS total
    FROM order_product
    WHERE order_id = '1'

    UNION ALL           
    SELECT order_id, price AS total
    FROM order_shipping
    WHERE order_id = '1'
) subtable
WHERE order_id <> 0 GROUP BY order_id
```

Now I want all orders where the amount paid (order_transaction) is less than the order total. I tried the following query, but it tells me:
`Unknown column 'o.id' in 'where clause'`. There are no linenumbers, but it is on line `12` in the query below.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS o.id
FROM `order` o
WHERE (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price),0) AS transactionTotal
        FROM order_transaction 
        WHERE order_id = o.id
      ) <=
      (
        SELECT SUM(total) AS orderTotal
        FROM (
            SELECT order_id, SUM(price * amount) AS total
            FROM order_product
            WHERE order_id = o.id

            UNION ALL           
            SELECT order_id, price AS total
            FROM order_shipping
            WHERE order_id = o.id
        ) subtable
        WHERE order_id <> 0 GROUP BY order_id
      ) 
ORDER BY o.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

I don't understand whey this is not working for the second subquery while it is working perfectly in the first subquery (on order_transaction table).

Expected result:

```
o.id 
------
 1
 2
 4
 8
 9
10
```

Below my database schema

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_product` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_shipping` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_transaction` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you make a text formatted table with the results you expect with this example data.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) how you can provide this.. Then you can verify if our query is correct..

Comment: Short answer: you can't co-related multiple times like that. You need to rewrite this to using joins.

Comment: From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html): "A derived table cannot be a correlated subquery."

Comment: You need something like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/85XyFz75w4nhzfYqvejQ1z/0 - But it doesn't return the "expected" result.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Indeed, it is missing the orders that do not have shipping costs (record in order_shipping). I'm now trying to work this out with left joins

Comment: What you are trying to do is to execute a subquery for each row of the main table `o`. That's called a "lateral subquery". MySQL does not support lateral subqueries. You would need to use Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, or SQL Server to run a query like this one. Sorry.

Comment: What is `order_shipping`? i assume these are transport costs on top on the order?

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, the total order cost is the sum of `order_product` and `order_shipping`. In the real application there are also `order_discount`, `order_servicecharge`. But I wanted to keep it simple in the example.

Comment: I think I got it with help of JOINS. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4MaVseQnmCkj84UGWYxDov/2

Comment: No @Timo002 you didn't got it see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4MaVseQnmCkj84UGWYxDov/4) because you are using GROUP BY in a invalid way..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Why dit you add `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. That breaks execution of the query

Comment: indeed @Timo002 forcing MySQL into giving correct data and not allowing to give data which you can't trust.. This is about money so you need to make **damn** sure you can trust the results.

Comment: Add unique keys: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f7LtHMheGtbotR9QpS9qFQ/0

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I don't understand. I needed to change the sql_mode on the db-fiddle site. My own database doesn't have this issue, this database setting is probably default for my hosting.

Comment: @Timo002 read [GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and how [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) works in MySQL.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I didn't add unique keys because they are not unique. The records can hold more than one row for each order. For example, someone can pay an order in two pieces.

Comment: @Timo002 - If order_id is not unique in order_shipping and order_transaction, then your query is wrong. It fails with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for a good reason.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, Something is still not working indeed. Will dive in the the `sql_mode`

Answer (score 0):

A subquery in a FROM clause (your UNION query) is called a *derived table*.

In [MySQL documentation about *Derived Tables*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) you will find this:

> A derived table cannot be a correlated subquery.

That means you cannot reference a table (alias) which is outside the scope of that subquery like here:

```
WHERE order_id = o.id
```

But you can write correlated subqueries in SELECT or WHERE clauses. Your query can be rewritten to:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS o.id
    , (
        SELECT IFNULL(SUM(price),0) AS transactionTotal
        FROM order_transaction 
        WHERE order_id = o.id
    ) a
    , (
        SELECT SUM(price * amount) AS total
        FROM order_product
        WHERE order_id = o.id
    ) b
    , (
        SELECT SUM(price) AS total
        FROM order_shipping
        WHERE order_id = o.id
    ) c
FROM `order` o
ORDER BY o.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;

HAVING a <= COALESCE(b, 0) + COALESCE(c, 0)
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6RZdyGuekW4geoZu3uBk9q/0)

It though doesn't return your expected result. To fix that, you probably need to change `<=` to `<`.